# Is there a way to get the system configuration files folder within a Perl script?

Tags: perl, configuration

Tried searching for this a number of ways and have not yet found an answer ...

***Background***

I am working on a legacy Perl application that has a lot of hard-coded values in it which should be configurable depending on where the app is installed. So, obviously, I am looking to externalize these values into a configuration file that may be located in one of a few "expected" locations. That is, using a traditional approach of checking for the configuration file in:

- the current working directory,
- the user's home directory (or a sub-folder therein), and
- the system configuration directory (or a sub-folder therein)

where the first one found wins.

***Where I am at***

Perused the CPAN site a bit and found the `Config::Any` package, which looks promising. I can give it a list of files to use:

```
use Config::Any;
my $config = Config::Any->load_files(
    {
        files => [qw(sample.conf /home/william/.config/sample.conf /etc/sample.conf)],
        use_ext => 0,
    });
```

This will check for the existence of each of these files, and, if found, load the contents into an array reference of hash references. Not bad, but I still have to hard-code the locations where I search for my `sample.conf` file. Here, I assume that I am working on a Linux system, and that the location for the configuration file for all users of the application is `/etc/`. I could always add `/usr/local/etc/` as well, but regardless, this is not system agnostic.

I can locate the user home folder using `File::HomeDir` for searching there, and it works correctly regardless of the system on which the application is running. So is there a similar package that would provide the `/etc/` folder (or its equivalent on other platforms)?

***Questions***

- Is there a way to do this without having to know what particular OS I am on? (Perl package or code snippet)
- What is the "Perl best practice" way of accomplishing this? I cannot imagine that no one else has run into this previously.

Comment: Have you considered using an environment variable to store the location?  Or, pass it to the script as a command line argument?

Comment: Unfortunately, it's a legacy CGI application, so I don't think those are options here. Eventually, I would like to migrate it to mod_perl and provide the configuration options in the Apache configuration, but the application is so large and undocumented, I don't see that happening any time soon; I'm stuck with working with it as it is. This is just a stepping stone in the direction of making the application more "deploy-friendly".

Comment: I would add that the options are part of the various packages that support the CGI scripts.

Comment: Why not keep it in (or under) the DocumentRoot or it could be kept anywhere in the filesystem and have a symbolic link to it in/under the DocumentRoot?

Comment: DocumentRoot is probably not the best place either as the file will contain user and database credentials, among other sensitive data. If someone knows the name of the file, it can be browsed from there. I'm really looking for a way that when I install the application, it puts a default configuration file out there for the admin user to modify while keeping it safe from prying eyes.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you don't plan to run your code on non unix-based hosts, according to the [conventional directory layout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_filesystem#Conventional_directory_layout) and [filesystem hierarchy standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard), you may rely on a quite large set of well known places.

Anyway, nothing prevents you to dynamically build the file search specification to take account of platform oddities and their specific ways to get them (eg. `File::HomeDir::Win32` vs `File::HomeDir`).